# MongoDb optimisation

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a MongoDB collection with 5,000 records (or thousands). I want to update this collection with new records.
These new records can be the same or with few updated records.

To do this, I have 2 approaches:

1. Iterate over these records and determine which ones to update (based on a condition). If the condition is truthy update the record.
2. Delete all the existing records (deleteMany), and then simply add new data.

Which one would be more performant and optimised? And why? Or this there another way?

Comment: Have you checked out [$merge](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/)?

Comment: Isn't this to merge two collections? @ray

Comment: The word "merge" has different meanings. But for your desired upsert behaviour, $merge is the canonical way to achieve that.

Comment: Did you click the link and read the docs for `$merge` that @ray provided? Separately, isn't "_determine which one to update (based on a condition)_" the first argument to the `update` command?

Comment: @user20042973 The docs doesn't suggest to use the same output collection as the one you're aggregating. Which is exactly what I need.

Comment: There's a whole section about it on that page [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#output-to-the-same-collection-that-is-being-aggregated) right?